# How to find a string in a text file and print it on screen

Tags: batch-file

The `laos.txt` file contains: `LastLogedUser=asdasd` and I want the script to return just the username (`asdasd`) without `LastLogedUser=`.

I tried like so:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "LastLogedUser=" %cd%\bin\laos.txt') do set "uniuser=%%a"
echo User is: %uniuser%
```

What it does it returns `LastLogedUser=asdasd` instead of just `asdasd`

How do I make it return just the username?

Comment: Use `for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /L "LastLogedUser=" .\bin\laos.txt') do set "uniuser=%%J"`. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help carefully from top of first page to bottom of last page. I recommend to do the same with `findstr /?`. Hint: This code does not work if the string after `LastLogedUser=` starts with one or more equal signs because of __FOR__ removes all of them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer to [Link](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html).

Using `%uniuser:~14%` will give you just the username.